# How to print sideways pyramid without using conditional statement?

Tags: c++

I have to print out a sideways pyramid:

```
O

OO

OOO

OOOO

OOO

OO

O
```

I have managed to do it using two for loops and an if statement but I want to know if it possible to do it using two for loops and no conditional statements.

```
char character = 79;
int temp = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    std::cout << character;
    
    if (i >= 4) 
    {
        temp = temp + 2;
    }

    for (int j = 0 + temp; j <= i; j++)
    {
        std::cout << character;
    }

    std::endl(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Where does `temp` come from?

Comment: @Chris I'm using temp just bc I couldn't think of any other way

Comment: `char character = 79;` Refrain from [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). Use `char character = 'O';` instead.

Comment: `temp` is almost `i*2`

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it with two loops an no conditional statements.  Consider `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` as your first loop and `for ( ; i < 7; i++)` as your second.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do with two (or 1, with a helper function) loops, nested. Oh, and some math.

Consider that we can write a function really easily to print a row.

```cpp
void print_row(char ch, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << ch;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If we call that we only need 1 loop. If we loop to a certain size, we really need to go to size times 2 minus 1. What number is generated each time?

```cpp
const int size = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2 - 1; i++) {
    ...
}
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

What we really need are these numbers, though, to give to `print_row`:

```
1
2
3
4
3
2
1
```

Up until we get to 5, it's all good. For 5 and above, we need to get back to lower numbers. We can use a ternary operator and some math to get there.

```cpp
const int size = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2 - 1; i++) {
    int len_of_row = (i <= size ? i : size - (i - size));
    print_row('0', len_of_row);
}
```

Let's pick that apart. `i - size` when `i` is 5 and `size` is 4 will give us `1`. If we subtract that from our `size`, we get `3`. If we do the same with `i` being `6`, we get `2`, and if we do it with `7` we get `1`.

Now, *maybe* the ternary is a cheat because it's a replacement for a conditional.

We can eliminate the ternary expression by taking advantage of operator precendence and how boolean logic short-circuits. We do have to rewrite `print_row` turn return `bool` and always return `true`.

```cpp
const int size = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2 - 1; i++) {
    i <= size && print_row('0', i) || print_row('0', size - (i - size);
}
```